# About the bandwith when using 301 redirect Post and Get

Tags: http

Im using ajax upload file to server_1 and use 301 header redirect to server_2.

The question is: The server_1 will lost bandwith Inbound and Outbound same size with server_2 ?

Thank you !!

Comment: I mean is full size of the file? or smaller than server_2 ? :D

Comment: The answer to THAT is ... No, obviously.  You need to read up on what a 301 redirect does; i.e. what happens when a web browser receives a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the `proxy` and `redirection` concepts.

**Proxy:**

1. User connect to Server 1
2. Server 1 connect to Server 2
3. All data sent by User to Server 1 is forwarded to Server 2 by Server 1 (User never see Server 2)

**Redirection**

1. User connect to Server 1
2. Server 1 tell user to use Server 2 instead
3. Server 1 is now out of the loop: User and Server 2 have a direct link

Now, your your particular case is a bit more complicated.

Redirecting a user on a HTTP POST query with 301/302 is not allowed (well it is allowed, but will change the method to GET).

You need to use a 307/308 code (which means "retry this query somewhere else but don't change it to GET".

When the user's browser makes a query with the file upload to `server_1`, it will receive the 307 response after uploading the file.

So both servers will waste the inbound bandwidth.